# How to disable getRows call on filter change

Tags: reactjs, pagination, ag-grid, infinite-scroll, ag-grid-react

I am using a server side data source for my AG Grid

```
            <AgGridReact
              animateRows
              sortable={false}
              enableRangeSelection
              rowGroupPanelShow="always"
              suppressDragLeaveHidesColumns
              onGridReady={this.onGridReady}
              columnDefs={gridColumns}
              defaultColDef={defaultColDef}
              enableCellTextSelection
              rowSelection="single"
              frameworkComponents={{
                dollarValueFormatter,
                largeTextCellRenderer,
                boolValueCellRenderer,
                trackingNumberCellRenderer,
                actionCellRenderer: actionCellRenderer(this),
              }}
              rowHeight={100} //TODO Fix
              autoGroupColumnDef={autoGroupColumnDef}

              rowModelType='infinite'
              pagination= {true}
              paginationPageSize= {ALL_RETURN_LINE_ITEMS_RMS_PAGE_SIZE}
              datasource={this.props.allReturnsDataSource()}
              cacheBlockSize={ALL_RETURN_LINE_ITEMS_RMS_PAGE_SIZE}
            />
```

I want to fetch the data for new pages from the server but i want the filtering on client side with the data present in the browser. However, right now whenever user applies a filter, getRows is called. How can i avoid call to getRows?

I can't find any such API